# Calculate and Show Result in TextView- Android Studio, Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Java /android studio, need help with this-

I have a TextinputEditText field- accountEt  (one can input number to this field)

I need to calculate and display- accountEt * ((100-3) / 100);
[Basically, if 100 entered it shows 97, if 10 entered it shows 9.7]

How to do this in android studio? > show the result (9.7) in a TextView properly.

Like-

> Textfield accountEt- [10]                | (edit text)
>  Result-
>   [9.7]                            |(text view)

Any help is useful.

Comment: Just a tip: the equation in your question can be simplified to `accountEt * 0.97 `

Answer (score 1):

1. Get edit Text value in String.
2. calculate the result and store in the String Data Type.
3. Show on String value on the Text View.

   String calculate=accountEt.getText.ToString();

   String newCalcualatedValue=calculate.toInt* ((100-3) / 100);

   textView.setText(newCalcualatedValue);

Answer (score 1):

If you use a button to calculate the result. In your button onclick listener just save the value of text value to string and calculate the resut using the value and store it another variable. And finally set the result to your edittext

`int a=Integer.parseInt(edittextname.gettext().tostring());
    float result=a * ((100-3) / 100);
    accountet.settext(Float.toString(result));`

Comment: I don't want to use button to calculate the result, it should set text automatically to the display textview upon entering/changing value in the edit text

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the text automatically on text input, do this:

```
accountEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        int num;
        if (text.isEmpty())
            num = 0;
        else
            num = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        double res = num * 0.97;
        result.setText(Double.toString(res));
    }
});
```

Comment: the float gives an error.. it says, the provided is a double

Comment: I have edited the answer, please make those changes.